# Matlab Vertcat function error

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Help I'm developing an application in matlab using the Vertcat functon.

But I got this error in Matlab..

```
    ??? Error using ==> vertcat
    CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

    Error in ==> imgMaskMed at 31
    copy_matrix = vertcat(copy_matrix, copy_matrix(a_temp,:));
```

Here is my code where the error located

```
      copy_matrix = vertcat(copy_matrix, copy_matrix(a_temp,:));
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know with the little information you provide, but my guess is that your `copy_matrix` has more than 2 dimensions. For example, if it's a 3D array you should use

```
copy_matrix = vertcat(copy_matrix, copy_matrix(a_temp,:,:));
```

If it's 4D use

```
copy_matrix = vertcat(copy_matrix, copy_matrix(a_temp,:,:,:));
```

and so on.

Comment: How about this code " copy_matrix = horzcat(copy_matrix, copy_matrix(:,:,b_temp));"
I got this Error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> imgMaskMed at 33
 copy_matrix = horzcat(copy_matrix, copy_matrix(:,:,b_temp));"

Comment: Actually i got that code from http://www.giassa.net/?page_id=635..
From Median Filter section.. My input is an rgb image